# You vs. Yourself?

Tags: reflexives

If a child points at a necklace his classmate is making, and he wonders if the classmate is making it for herself or for someone else, which of the following is more appropriate?

> "Is this for you?"

or

> "Is this for yourself?"

Comment: i don't think children know the difference

Answer (score 1):

One would use the reflexive pronoun *yourself* when its antecedent precedes it within the same clause. This is not the case in your sentence so "Is this for you?" is correct. If instead the sentence were, "Are you making this for yourself?" it would require the reflexive.

Comment: Depends on where you are, too. In Ireland, “Is this for yourself?” is perfectly fine.